# Looking for suggestions for more efficient Excel FILTER solution

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm creating a dashboard that will return data based on a user selection of two criteria, in this case the agencies that made a referral will be returned based on the quarter and program they referred into.

The tricky thing is, I wish the user to be able to select both or either of the criteria to search. That is, a user should have the choice to see all agencies who referred in 2023-Q1 for Program A, or all agencies that referred in 2023-Q1, or all all agencies who have referred to Program A. As there may be multiple agencies per period/program, I used the FILTER function rather than V or XLOOKUP.

Before posting what I tried, let me show the final variant which I got to work:

> =IF(AND($F$2<>"",$G$2<>""),(FILTER(Table4[Agency],(Table4[Session]=Dashboard!$F$2)*(Table4[Program]=Dashboard!$G$2))),IF($F$2<>"",(FILTER(Table4[Agency],(Table4[Session]=Dashboard!$F$2))),
> IF($G$2<>"",
> (FILTER(Table4[Agency],(Table4[Program]=Dashboard!$G$2))))))

My data is stored in a table for expandability, and there are many other fields which are referenced elsewhere.

I started with

> =FILTER(Table4[Agency],(Table4[Session]=Dashboard!$F$2)*(Table4[Program]=Dashboard!$G$2))

with AND logic to produce a list when both search terms were present.

To add in the OR logic, I thought I could do something like:

> =IFERROR((FILTER(Table4[Agency],(Table4[Session]=Dashboard!$F$2)*(Table4[Program]=Dashboard!$G$2))),
> (FILTER(Table4[Agency],(Table4[Session]=Dashboard!$F$2)+(Table4[Program]=Dashboard!$G$2)))

to first try filtering for both terms, then do an OR search if both terms weren't present; however, getting the either/or type search to work was challenging and resulted in a large number of results being returned, where it seemed that it was matching the blank search term against blank lines of my table.

My solution works, but it seems kind of janky, and I am concerned about the impact on future scalability, and so I'm wondering if anyone has a better solution.

Comment: can you set your data as a table and use excel's slicer? the main difference is slicers work directly on the orginal data while filter builds a new list based on the orignal data

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @gns100, but because I'm trying to build a dashboard (which also has data displayed from other tables), building a new list is what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve this. Consider the following table:

[image]

Create 2 lists to be used in the dropdown, by stacking a simple "*" with unique values that can be selected in both the Agency and the Session, using the VSTACK function:

[image]

Create the 2 filters the user can select, by adding a drop down menu linked to the 2 lists you created. You can use the reference $M$5# to expand the list automatically if new Agencies/Sessions are added.

[image]

To filter your table using both filter, you can use the following formula. The "*" will serve as a wildcard when selected in either filter.

```
=FILTER(Table[Item],ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$2,Table[Agency])) * ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$3,Table[Session])))
```

If you need to add another filter, you simply need to add another ISNUMBER() element like above. The * in between will act as an 'and' operator.

This solution works with any combinaison, and having an empty filter also acts as a wildcard:

[image]

Obviously you can store the lists in a separate, hidden sheet. Since they're dynamic and based on all the unique values of your data table, they will expand automatically and don't need to be modified if you add new values.

Once you have a filtered list, you can also add any other value from your data table using an XLOOKUP like this:

[image]